# как разбить строку на триады

Tags: java, jsp

Ребят нужна помощь, вот например есть строка которую получаю из запроса в 
виде - `32 33936 32`нужно разбить ее на триады и вставить символ "-" между триадами, то есть должно получится так "32-33-936-32" и потом удалить все пробелы, в базе перед двузначными числами стоят пробелы. На страницу вывожу переменную так - `<c:out value="${vp44150sql.nc}" />`

Comment: Какие же это **три**ады, если группы содержат по два символа? И как код должен понять в какой группе должно быть два символа, а в какой три?

Comment: в базе перед двузначными числами стоят пробелы получается три символа

Comment: regex `(?:(?:\s)|(\S))(..)` на `-$1$2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SomeBean.java**

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class GroupingBean {
    private String[] chunks;
    private String delimiter;
    private int size;

    public String getDelimiter() {
        return delimiter;
    }

    public void setDelimiter(String delimiter) {
        if (delimiter == null || delimiter.isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Разделитель должен быть установлен!");

        this.delimiter = delimiter;
    }

    public Integer getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(Integer size) {
        if (size < 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Размер группы должен быть положительным числом!");

        this.size = size;
    }

    public void setChunks(String src) {
        if (delimiter == null || size == 0)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Не установлен разделитель или размер группы!");

        int chunksCount = (int) Math.ceil((double) src.length() / (double) size);
        chunks = new String[chunksCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++)
            chunks[i] = src.substring(i * size, Math.min(src.length(), (i + 1) * size));
    }

    public String getChunks() {
        if (chunks == null)
            return "";

        return Arrays.stream(chunks)
                 .map(String::trim)
                 .collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter));
    }
}
```

**some_page.jsp**

```
<jsp:useBean id="grouper" class="com.example.GroupingBean">
    <jsp:setProperty name="grouper" property="delimiter" value="-"/>
    <jsp:setProperty name="grouper" property="size" value="3"/>
</jsp:useBean>

<c:set target="${grouper}" property="chunks" value="${vp44150sql.nc}" />

<c:out value="${grouper.chunks}" />
```

Comment: подчеркивает `<jsp:setProperty property="delimiter" value="-"/>` пишет - SetProperty: Mandatory attribute name missing

Comment: Исправил, проверьте.

Comment: спасибо большое, а если нужно будет сделать и для другой переменной я так же добавлю `<c:set target="${grouper}" property="chunks" value="${другая переменная}" />`?

Comment: Да, конечно. Лишь бы это была строковая переменная. Бин разобьёт ещё по количеству символов указанных в `size`. А при выводе объединит с помощью символа указанного в `delimiter`.

Comment: спасибо большое, очень полезная штука этот бин, можете скинуть хороший источник где о нем можно почитать?

Comment: [Вот например](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1826679/) маленькая и простенькая книжка, доходчиво описывающая необходимый минимум для jsp-кодера.

Comment: а еще вопросик, на счет второй переменной, это нужно как-то менять имя property, а то как оно поймет тут `<c:out value="${grouper.chunks}" />` какую из двух переменных мне нужно вывести на страницу?

Comment: Выражение `${grouper.chunks}` приведёт к вызову геттера бина, который вернёт сгруппированую строку.

Comment: получается я не смогу на одной странице, разбить так допустим три переменные, и вывести их отдельно в разных тегах <td> таблицы, оно выведет сразу группу в которую будут входить три переменные?

Comment: Вы можете создать три бина. Или вместо бина можете написать свой тег, который будет делать то же самое, не храня состояние. Или зарегистрировать функцию для вызова из EL.

Comment: из всего вышеперечисленного знаю только как три бина сделать)) спасибо еще раз)